# Difference between `==` and `and`

Tags: python-3.x

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if negative:
    return (a < 0 and b < 0)
  else:
    return ((a < 0 == b > 0) or (a > 0 == b < 0))
```

so basically I tried some basic problems.
I just started out and went to https://codingbat.com/prob/p162058 to try it and don't understand why if I were to replace the '==' with 'and' it would work? Thanks.

Oh, I got it now, thanks guys. :D
(this python community is fire!!!)

Comment: That's like asking "what's the difference between == and &&"

Comment: The difference you observe happens because the comparison operators `>` and `<` takes precedence over the `and` operator, but not over `==`.

Comment: for comparing boolean values, nothing. For comparing non-booleans, `==` means equality whereas `and` converts both sides to a bool before chekcing

Comment: @Felierix that's because that's what they're asking.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy that's wrong; `False and False` is `False`, whereas `False == False` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

`and` is a logical operator and returns true only when both the expressions we are using it on are true.

`==` is used for comparisons and returns true when both expressions are equal; they don't need to be true.

To give you an example `False == False` will return `True` but `False and False` will return `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're learning, you might be interested in seeing that this is an equivalent function.

- basically it does a bit wise &  and returns true if the result is < 0
- else a bit wise exclusive or and returns true if the result is < 0

```
def pos_neg(a , b, negative):
      if negative:
         return (a & b) < 0  # both sign bits set (i.e. neg), return true
      else:
         return (a ^ b) < 0  # different signs, return true
```

In both cases, it is the `sign bit` of the result that is of concern. If the bit is set then the value will be negative (hence the comparison to < 0)

Answer (score 0):

This "==" means equals to, belonging to Python Comparison Operators, used to compare two values.

and language keyword "and" it is for Python Logical Operators used to combine conditional statements.

You should check out this, it may solve others doubts you have.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)

Answer (score 0):

All your relational operator usages (i.e. `a < 0`, `b < 0`, etc.) result to a boolean value and thus these are known as boolean expressions.

When you put `a < 0`, think of it like a test of: "is `a` less than 0, true or false?".

So, if both `a` and `b` are negative (i.e. less than zero), their expressions will return true.

So on the line `return a < 0 and b < 0`, replacing `and` with `==` is like saying `return true == true`.  Without the change it'd be `return true and true`.

Note: This does not mean `==` is the same as `and`.  `==` checks for equality of the left-hand side to the right-hand side (e.g. `1 == 1`) and gives a true or false value depending on the result of equality.  `and` checks for if the left-hand side results to a `true` statement and if the `right-hand` side results to a `true` statement in order to result to a `true` expression.